# Css3 Box-shadow property is appearing on all sides except the bottom

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for the box I'm applying the shadow on.

```
width: 295px;
max-width:90%;
height: auto;
padding-bottom:20px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:50px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
position:relative;
```

The 3 boxes of Beautiful Design Valid Code Structure and Seo Integrated all carry this box-shadow property but it doesn't appear at the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Can you post a like to a fiddle of it? or the page itself?

Comment: [Works here](http://jsfiddle.net/ajgpc/).

Comment: I ran the code in fiddle and its displaying the bottom shadow. I know the code is all fine still don't know why its not working for me.

Comment: The shadow also appears when I reduce the width of my browser and the due to the decrease in width as soon as the floated boxes shift on top of each other the shadow appears.

Comment: @AsaadMahmood Does that `#process` div have `overflow:hidden` on it at all, and it is smaller than the height of the inner boxes?

Comment: the #process has the code below

Comment: position:relative;
width:930px;
height:auto;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
max-width:90%;
overflow:auto;

Comment: If its hard to read I'll tell you that it has the propertly overflow:auto and also has height auto

Comment: And one more thing, when I remove overflow:auto, I can see the box-shadow but then my floated elements have no height, then I would have to use the clearfix, however I use overflow:auto to have the floated objects retain their height

Comment: Giving it a height also fixed the problem but then it would ruin the structure.

Comment: Why would it ruin the structure?

Comment: Because If I give it a fixed height, then the floated divs would easily exceed the container seeing as this is a responsive site, and the height of the container for these boxes should vary depending on the browser width or device width.

Comment: Ahh, I see, and a clearfix is out of the question because?

Comment: Its because I don't like it, I've been using overflow:auto and overflow:hidden for floating divs uptill now and they've worked like a charm, if there is however no solution for this problem I would have to use the clearfix. I just wanted to know if there was a solution.

Comment: Fixed it, just gave it a margin-bottom, don't know why I couldn't think of that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a bounding box around these grouped elements that might have a size restriction applied to it that is somehow cutting off the box-shadow on the bottom of that last element?

Have you tried clearing your float?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uriahjamesgd_73/5fQPV/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box clear"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>​

/* CSS */
.box {
  position:relative;  
  width: 75px;
  max-width:90%;
  height: 75px;
  padding:0 0 20px 0;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px #CCC; 
}
.clear {
  clear:left;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem is with your box-shadow property.

Try this:

```
.box{
width: 295px;
max-width:90%;
height: auto;
padding-bottom:20px;
float:left;
text-align:center;
margin-left:10px;
margin-top:50px;
background-color: white;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #ccc;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #ccc;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 2px #ccc;
position:relative;
}
```

Check out [this](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow) link for more experiments.

If it still doesn't work looks like some element might have a size restriction applied that is somehow cutting off the box-shadow on the bottom of that last element.

Hope it helps :)